# How find special word in string by regex

Tags: regex

I want to find **foo** in a string by regex except **foo** which is in alt tag like this alt="foo"; For example this is my string:

```
This is an example foo and foo alt="foo"
```

I want to find all **foo** in this string except **foo** in this part: `alt="foo"`, so the regex should find just two **foo** that are bold below:

> This is a example **foo** and **foo** alt="foo"

Comment: Find all that arent quoted, is that what you want?

Comment: no. I mean all foo that are not like this : alt="foo"

Comment: @Atefeh then change `(?!<")` to `(?!<alt=")`

Comment: @Atefeh That sounds like a pretty vague specification. So any **foo**, as long as it is not preceded by **alt="** and followed by **"**? Based on that specification you would find for example the foos in: bar "**foo**" bar alt="**foo**bar", but maybe that is intentional...

Comment: @MarounMaroun its good but this will not match string like `foo"`

Comment: Parse HTML with a normal parser, and you will have much less headache with regexps. Also, depending on what regex flavor you are using, the regex-based answer can be really trivial.

Answer (score 1):

If the `alt=` part is always after the words you want to match, you can do it with this regex :

```
(?<!alt=")\b(\w+)\b(?=.*alt="\1")
```

I use `\b` word boundaries to make sure it only matches full words and not parts of others.

You can see it in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/sR3eY4/4).

If you want to match words after the `alt=` part it becomes harder, since lookbehind are 0-width and thus can't use quantifiers to search back as far as needed in the string.
In this case I think the easiest solution is to make the search in two steps :

- first search the tokens with `(?<=alt=")[^"]+`
- then search the matches with `(?<!alt=")\b$token\b` where `$token` should be replaced by the value previously matched

Comment: fails for `This is an example foo and foo alt="foo"foo and foo alt="foo"`

Comment: @rock321987 thanks, added a negative lookbehind to fix that